# Boton para cerrar Actividad en Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tengo un boton en mi segunda actividad (mensajes_predet)

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/Button40"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick=""
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Que debe de cerrar mi actividad para regresar a la actividad primaria, estoy tratando con el codigo:

```
Button cerrar= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40); 
cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish(); 
}
});
```

Al momento de insertarlo en el archivo java de mi segunda actividad justo debajo de:

```
package com.globalstar.st300r;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MensajesPredet extends Activity  {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes_predet);

}

Button cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40);
cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
        finish();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mensajes_predet, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Y este es el java de mi primer actividad:

```
package com.globalstar.st300r;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void predefinido(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MensajesPredet.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

pero me marca 4 errores:

1) al colocarlo me detecta el @override como comentario y me marca la leyenda "Annotations are not allowed here"

2) en el codigo cerrar.SetOnClickListener marca (Cannot resolve symbol) y SetOnclickListener en rojo

3) (View v) marca error

4) Onclick is never used

Agradeceria su apoyo!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es tu código de la segunda actividad:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes_predet);

}

Button cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40);
cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
       finish();

}
```

debería ser así

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes_predet);

   Button cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40);
   cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            finish();

    });
}
```

todos los eventos a asociados con controles de android deben ser inicializados en el método onCreate() de su respectiva Actividad

Comment: Muchas Gracias @soulblack, es usted el amo!!

Answer (score 0):

Los 4 problemas son relacionados a que estas declarando el botón fuera de `onCreate()` que es donde cargas en layout `activity_main.xml` que contiene el botón; tienes que agregar dentro la obtención de la referencia del botón y su listener:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes_predet);

    /* Boton */
    Button cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40);
    cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
         finish();

      });
    /*****/


}
```

Pero hay otro detalle, elimina la propiedad `android:onClick` desde tu layout, ya que el botón tiene un listener para este objetivo.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/Button40"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:focusable="true"

    android:clickable="true" />
```

Si deseas usar la  propiedad   `android:onClick` , no definas el listener del botón:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensajes_predet);

/* Boton */
/*Button cerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button40);
cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
        finish();

});*/

}
```

solo define el método mediante la  propiedad `android:onClick`, por ejemplo `finalizar` :

y declara el método en código:

```
public void finalizar(View v){
    finish();
}
```

En realidad como puedes ver son 2 formas diferentes de activar el clic en un botón!.